# Pandas str.split() is not working properly with regex

Tags: python, pandas, split

My data :

```
            Page
    www.google/somedata/1514
    www.google/somedata/8249984
```

What I want is :

```
  Page                              TBID   
www.google/somedata/1514            1514
www.google/somedata/8249984         8249984
```

My code :

```
import pandas as pd 

# intialise data of lists. 
data = {'Page':['www.google/somedata/1514', 'www.google/somedata/8249984']} 

# Create DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

# Print the output. 
df['TBID'] = df['Page'].str.extract('(\d*)', expand=True) 
df
```

it is showing blank data ,not sure why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\d+` for match all numbers and `expand=False` for return `Series`:

```
df['TBID'] = df['Page'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False) 
print (df)
                          Page     TBID
0     www.google/somedata/1514     1514
1  www.google/somedata/8249984  8249984
```